# HTML/CSS Images zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm developing my own website for fun and I have a problem.

I've got a homepage where I have 3 images, initially transparents. When I put the mouse on one of them, the chosen one will zoom itself and become full visible (1.0 opacity and scale 1.10). While becoming zoomed, the chosen image is covered a bit by the next one (I think it's because of their positioning in the code...). So: I don't want to resize them, because they are in their right size; I just want to know if it is possible to zoom-out (to shrink? sorry, I don't know the right word) the not-chosen images, while the chosen one is zoomed (I used the event "hover" to zoom the images). Is it possible to "concatenate" many events?

Here's the code:

```
 img {
        
            opacity: 0.5;
        
        }
        
        img:hover {
        
            -webkit-transform:scale(1.10);
            opacity: 1.0;
            
        }
```

```
        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
            <center>

             <a href="link" style="color:black; hover:black;"><img src="im1.jpg" alt="" border="5"/></a>
             <a href="link" style="color:black; hover:black;" target="_blank"><img src="img2.jpg" alt="" border="5" style="background-color:white;"/></a>
             <a href="link" style="color:black; hover:black;"><img src="img3.jpg" alt="" border="5" height="168px"/></a>

            </center>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: Please include the code you have for this, so we can help.

Comment: You can use javascript to change the remaining images but as @FluffyKitten noted above, without code it will be hard to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this without javascript by changing the z-index of the active image. Basically move the hovered image to the front:

```
.img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.img:hover{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Here is a codepen for it https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GMrZwj

Comment: Thanks! That's what i need. Thanks everyone and have a nice day :)